# Difference between catch vs catch and rethrow exception in java?

Tags: java, exception

We can throw exception by `try-catch` or `throw`

**Scenario 1:**

```
public void testMethod() throws MyException
{
   throw new MyException();
}
```

**Scenario 2:**

```
public void testMethod() throws MyException
{
   try
   {
      throw new MyException();
   }
   catch(MyException e)
   {
      throw e;
   }
}
```

In the above code block

1. Do we really want to catch and rethrow exception instead of directly throw the exception?
2. Which scenario is best way to handle exception?
3. If scenario 2, please explain

Comment: You do not need to rethrow exception, and scenario 1 is better but in scenerio one use try-catch to catch exception, so if you need to do some work after exception occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the need of throws is to intimate the compiler that the following code is expected to have a that type of exception such that to handle it if you want.
In both scenarios it fully dependent upon the business needs because if the Exception of any Java Standard  needs to be Wrapped in Custom Exception you need to handle it either by Wrapping around it as exception that has business explanation or to make a different execution based on parameters of the exception.

In scenario 2 there is no need to rethrow it untill it need to be explicitly throwed for any further code flow need to be executed instead of leaving it to complier.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

Scenario 2 can only makes sense when you want to have code that will be executed when `MyException` is thrown, e.g. you want to log that exception. If that is not the case then there is no point in adding a catch block and rethrowing the exception.

Comment: Ideally resources should be freed in `finally` block. And it's not suggested to both *log* and *re-throw* an exception. It's better to do just one of them.

Comment: @RohitJain I don't think this last is true in every situation.  I can envision that you may want to rethrow an exception, but log information that won't be available after you rethrow, such as method parameters.

Comment: @RohitJain Thanks for the note about freeing resources, fixed the question.

Answer (score 0):

In scenario 2 you have the option `to do some work` by catching it(e.g. wrapping it into your custom exception, do some book keeping etc.)  before you throw it further. But if you do not process the exception and simply throw then IMO both are same.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are throwing MyException you don't have to actually catch it and rethrow it unless you need to do some logging or any specific task in the catch.

But you still can have a catch blocks for other exceptions types and then wrap those exceptions with say MyException. This will give you a clear trace on the exception trail.

Eg:

```
public void doSomething() throws MyException {
    try {
        throw new MyException("Some Message");
    }
   catch(MyException e) {
      // Only IF YOU NEED TO EXPLICITLY LOG IT OR HANDLE IT.
       throw new MyException("A Message of failure",e)
    }
    catch(SomeOtherException e) {
      // LOG or HANDLE IT.
       throw new MyException("A Message of failure",e)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to throw a custom exception instead of actual exception then you should throw exception in catch but if you are throwing the same exception in catch them it is of no use.

Answer (score 0):

Usage for Scenario 2

Case 1: Get rid of checked exception i.e. `throws MyException` clause and throwing a `RuntimeException` instead,

Case 2: To log or call some Alert service etc. before re-throwing the exception up the stack